# SQL search results in order of what was searched

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

I want the server to give me the results of a query in the order I send it.

So if I write:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column in (9,1,8)
```

I would like it to give me the results in the order: 9,1,8

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Might help](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `left join`:

```
select t.*
from (select 9 as c, 1 as priority union all select 1, 2 union all select 8, 3
     ) vals left join
     table t
     on t.column = vals.c
order by vals.priority;
```

Note:  This is generic syntax.  The specific syntax for the subquery may differ depending on the database.

Another method uses `case` in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.column in (9, 1, 8)
order by (case column when 9 then 1 when 1 then 2 when 8 then 3 end);
```

Once again, this can be simplified in some databases, say by using special functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE` expression in order you want, something like:

```
select *
from table_name
where column_name in (9,1,8)
order by case column_name 
                 when 9 then 1 
                 when 1 then 2 
                 when 8 then 3 end
         , column_name -- optional, but here could go another column if you want to have custom order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in Oracle SQL if you have

```
SELECT Column_name
FROM user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
and Column_id in (9,1,8)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column IN (9, 1, 8)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column = 9 THEN 1
              WHEN column = 1 THEN 2
              WHEN column = 8 THEN 3
         END
```